# DNN simultaneous User Registration is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have created a custom module to register user in DNN using `UserController.CreateUser(ref userinfo)` and it is working for single user. When Single user trying to register it register but problem is when multiple user or simultaneously user trying to register it is register only one user and other user is getting exception. I have already tried with `ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(userInfo);` method but not working .

Comment: Can you show some code? How are you trying to add multiple users at once? And it seems to me that `ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile` will not add multiple users, just update the profile for one.

Comment: I am using only `UserCreateStatus userCreateStatus = UserController.CreateUser(ref pakUserInfo);` to register user but when 3-4 user simultaneously click on OK button only one user register and other got `UnExpectedError` exception

Comment: How and where do you create `pakUserInfo`? Update your question with the relevant snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the code below, I get 5 new registered users. Adapt this snippet to your needs to register multiple users at once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    UserInfo newUser = new UserInfo();
    newUser.Username = "Username_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.PortalID = base.PortalId;
    newUser.DisplayName = "DisplayName_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Email = "Email_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.FirstName = "FirstName_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.LastName = "LastName_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.IsSuperUser = false;
    newUser.Profile.Street = "Street_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Profile.City = "City_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Profile.Country = "Country_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Profile.PostalCode = "PostalCode_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Profile.Telephone = "Telephone_" + i.ToString();
    newUser.Profile.PreferredLocale = PortalSettings.DefaultLanguage.ToString();
    newUser.Membership.Password = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(25, 30));
    newUser.Membership.Approved = true;
    newUser.Membership.UpdatePassword = false;

    UserCreateStatus userCreateStatus = UserController.CreateUser(ref newUser);
}
```